# terminal: true and priority > 100 causes "@" parameter to stop working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

The code below "breaks" interpolated scope value `p1: "@"`. Am I doing something wrong or is this an Angular bug?

```
.directive("foo", function($compile){
  return {
    terminal: true,
    priority: 200, // anything > 100
    templateUrl: "foo.html",
    scope: {
      p1: "@", // doesn't work
      p2: "=", // works
      p3: "&"  // works
    },
    link: function(scope, element){
      // this also doesn't help
      $compile(element.contents())(scope);
    }
  };
});
```

The template `foo.html` is:

```
<div>{{p1}}</div>
<div>{{p2}}</div>
```

The output for `<foo p1="{{name}}" p2="name" ng-init="name = 'something'"></foo>` is:

```
{{name}}
something
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/v7MIOn1ABd8VomEBy5Oy?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The problem is with the priority that you have set on the directive.**

Normally, *The priority is only relevant when you have multiple directives on one element. The priority determines in what order those directives will be applied/started. In most cases you wouldn't need a priority, but sometimes when you use the compile function, you want to make sure that your compile function runs first.*

**Now the problem in your case is that you have set the priority of your 
directive as 200. Where as the priority of the {{}} interpolation  is
100.**

Hence in your case, even before the values are interpolated, the directive compiles and hence your p1 attribute has a value of {{something}}.

> Keep the priority of your directive anything less than 100 and things
>   will work out as expected.

Comment: Right, but then why doesn't manual invocation of `$compile` help?

Comment: Ah, I think I just go it. The variable `p1` is assigned a string `"{{name}}"`

Comment: Exactly. You got that pretty quickly, in less than 1 minute to be precise :D